# AEM Query date range property to query

Tags: aem, query-builder

I have a query as below:

```
path=/home/project/users
property=customGroup
property.value=Unverified
type=rep:User
```

From this result I need to filter whose

registrationCompletedDate or jcr:createdDate value is grater than 5 days
Both these properties are of type Date.

Can you help how I need to modify the query by adding the datarange propertyy?

Answer (score 2):

You can alter your query such as this:

```
relativedaterange.property=jcr:createdDate
relativedaterange.upperBound=5d
```

or

```
daterange.property=jcr:createdDate
daterange.upperBound=2020-09-10T00:00
```

You'll need to change the upperBound date to be 5 days prior to when you run the query if you use the second option.  These references will likely be useful for different query needs:

- https://github.com/paulrohrbeck/aem-links/blob/master/querybuilder_cheatsheet.md
- https://hashimkhan.in/2015/12/02/query-builder/